# Swift: Only appendContentsOf to unique elements

Tags: swift

Given two array

```
var array1 = [['id':0], ['id':1], ['id':2], ['id':3]];
var array2 = [['id'=3], ['id':4], ['id':5], ['id':6]];
```

how can I do a

```
array1.appendContentsOf(array2)
```

so that only unique elements are added.

Current array1.appendContentsOf(array2) 
 results in

```
[['id':0], ['id":1], ['id':2], ['id':3], ['id':3], ['id':4], ['id':5], ['id':6]]
```

where id:3 is duplicated.

Comment: What is this? It's not valid Swift syntax.

Comment: Better now? Your solution doesn't work though for an array of dictionaries.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let array1 = [0,1,2,3]
let array2 = [3,4,5,6]

Array(Set(array1).union(array2)) // [2,4,5,6,0,1,3]
```

If you want the order to stay the same, you can test each new value to see if the first array already contains it:

```
var array3 = array1
for element in array2 where !array1.contains(element) {
    array3.append(element)
}
// array3 now is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Or shorter:

```
var array3 = array1
array3.appendContentsOf(array2.filter { !array1.contains($0) })
// array3 now is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**Edit**

I don't think an array of dictionaries (each containing a single key-value pair) makes a lot of sense, but this works:

```
let array1 = [["id": 0], ["id": 1], ["id": 2], ["id": 3]]
let array2 = [["id": 3], ["id": 4], ["id": 5], ["id": 6]]

var array3 = array1
array3.appendContentsOf(array2.filter { !array1.map { $0["id"]! }.contains($0["id"]!) })
```